# How can i disable the autocomplete of highstocks

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

and what i do is to read a json file, that doesn't have all lines.

For example i have this json:

```
13.03.14 08:00    8°C
13.03.14 08:10    10°C
13.03.14 08:20    11°C
missing (08:30)   
13.03.14 08:40    9°C
```

So what highstock does is to fill the missing gap automatically with the follow data.
That means in my example:

```
13.03.14 08:30   9°C
```

So what i want is, that i have the value null inside, that i have a gap in my chart.

Does anybody now how to configure this ?

My highstock code:

```
$.getJSON('./file-read', function(data) {

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },

                title : {
                    text : 'Temperature'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    ordinal: false
                },

                series : [{
                    name : 'Temperature',
                    data : data,
                    marker : {
                        enabled : true,
                        radius : 3
                    },
                    shadow : true,
                    tooltip : {
                        valueDecimals : 2
                    }
                }]
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `gapSize: 1`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1007/

Or create null points when you don't have data: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1008/

```
    series: [{
        // gapSize: 1, set gapSize
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 2, 13, 8, 0), 8],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 2, 13, 8, 10), 10],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 2, 13, 8, 20), 11],
            // [Date.UTC(2014, 2, 13, 8, 30), null], // OR create null points
            [Date.UTC(2014, 2, 13, 8, 40), 9]
            ],
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 3
        },
        shadow: true,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
```

Comment: ok, thank you, that works with gapSize, can i highlight this gap with something. For example to make a red point, or a red line between the gap ?

Comment: There's no such way. If you want to mark this with some empty point, then you need create another scatter series where you will have all missing points.